# Why does reducer stop working after this code?

Tags: logging, hadoop, hdfs, reduce

I am following a simple example provided in one of the popular hadoop textbooks. The code is as follows:-
[Explanation of my issue follows after the program]

```
package src.main.myjob;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.lang.model.SourceVersion;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configured;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.KeyValueTextInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapReduceBase;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.OutputCollector;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Reporter;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.Tool;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner;

public class MyJob extends Configured implements Tool
{
    public static class MapClass extends MapReduceBase implements Mapper<Text, Text, Text, Text>
    {

        @Override
        public void map(Text key, Text value, OutputCollector<Text, Text> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException 
        {
        output.collect(value, key); 
        }
    }

    public static class Reduce extends MapReduceBase implements Reducer<Text, Text, Text, Text>
    {
            public void reduce(Text key, Iterator<Text> values, OutputCollector<Text, Text> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException
            {
                String csv = "";
                while(values.hasNext())
                {
        csv += values.next().toString();
                        csv += ",";
                }
                output.collect(key, new Text(csv));
            }
    }


    @Override
    public int run(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        JobConf job = new JobConf(conf, MyJob.class);

        Path in = new Path(args[0]);
        Path out = new Path(args[1]);

        FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(job, in);
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, out);

        job.setJobName("MyJob");
        job.setMapperClass(MapClass.class);
        job.setReducerClass(Reduce.class);

        job.setInputFormat(KeyValueTextInputFormat.class);
        job.setOutputFormat(TextOutputFormat.class);

        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);

        job.set("key.value.seperator.in.input.line", ",");

        JobClient.runJob(job);

        return 0;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        int res = ToolRunner.run(new Configuration(), new MyJob(), args);

        System.exit(res);
    }


}
```

Now for the benefit of the reader all this program does it processes a file [huge file] containing lines of citing patent id & cited patent id and inverts it. So in essence the output file has all the patent ids listed, each one followed by a comma separated list of citing patent ids.

When I try to execute it the Map task runs very well, however the reduce task gets stuck at 66%. I tried various things like examining logs (very cryptic & hardly useful) and increasing the number of reducers. However I have very little success understanding the problem. The code looks straight forward to me. I would really appreciate your inputs in helping me understand how to debug this issue here. I don't see anything obviously wrong with this program.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, please consider using `StringBuilder` in the reducer to append if you are trying to concatenate strings. That loop will that way perform way better if the size of the data is huge.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append(values.next().toString());
```

Then make sure you have enough memory in the reducers if you are having a very huge set of data to be processed.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I wish I can test this out however the data-node is not starting up. I wonder why Hadoop is so inconsistent in behavior. It's seems far easier to develop the MapReduce application than to administer Hadoop/HDFS => Harderst part is Debugging/Admin rather than development....

Comment: I think you don't have enough disk space. Have you checked that?

Comment: Putting Datanode logs here will take some waiting. I don't have access to my Hadoop Developer PC right now....

Comment: Ok, I did my research and looked into the logs and it seems to be an issue with namespaceIDs not matching. Looks like it is a well documented issue, but just for the records I solved it by deleting the ....hadoop/tmp/dfs/name/...." directory...... That solved the issue. Now I am off to testing you suggestion. Lets hope the reducer will complete its task. I Will post back the results...

Answer (score 0):

As an addendum to this question, I did finally succeed in completing my MapReduce programs. I had to increase the memory allocation of hadoop to 6 Gigs inside mapred-site.xml & also use string builder as JthRocker suggests in the above posts. It did complete, however the output file is unreadable. ubuntu indicates that it's size is 258MB which is marginally smaller than my input file. I was wondering it its a deficiency with my code itself? or if the data is not being properly written in an editor friendly format giving it interpretation problems? All inputs on this is highly appreciated.